# C# wp-json api (404) error not found

Tags: c#, wordpress, rest, wp-api

I'm trying to post on wordpress via wp-api but i'm getting the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

I can't understand since the plugin is working fine when I go to the link: http://example.com/wp-json/ I'm getting json data as expected, I don't get any error which tells me the plugin is working correctly. My code is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WordpressPost
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var uri = "http://www.example.com/wp-json/";
        var username = "user";
        var password = "password";

        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());

        string json = "{\"title\":\"Hello World!\",\"content_raw\":\"Content\",\"excerpt_raw\":\"Excerpt\"}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Close();

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

I have installed the two needed plugins JSON Basic Authentication, WP REST API and also enabled the pretty permalinks. What am I doing wrong ?

I'm new to c# that's why i chose the basic authentication login.

Comment: Hey, did you resolve that?